# Empty DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have List based on class (id, name, code, price) and im trying to add that values to datagrid. Problem is that, datagrid is still empty, i mean look like that:
[image]

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="275" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="337,51,0,0" Name="dataGridProducts" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="403" Foreground="#FF803E3E">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="30" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nazwa" Width="200" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kod" Width="120" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cena" Width="100" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
private void categoryListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnect().ConnectToSql();
    using (SqlConn)
    {
        SqlConn.Open();
        SqlCommand fillCategories = new SqlCommand("...", SqlConn);
        SqlDataReader rdr1;
        rdr1 = fillCategories.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr1.Read())
        {
            Products p = new Products(rdr1.GetInt32(rdr1.GetOrdinal("ID")), rdr1.GetString(rdr1.GetOrdinal("ProductName")), rdr1.GetString(rdr1.GetOrdinal("Barcode")), rdr1.GetString(rdr1.GetOrdinal("Price")));
            completeProductList.Add(p);
        }
    }
    dataGridProducts.ItemsSource = completeProductList;
}
```

Is there any solution how to fix it?

Comment: you need to share your xaml part of this at least. Class declarations would help as well.

Comment: Oh damn i entered xaml code here, but looks so bad.
Here is link to xaml and class:
http://pastebin.com/RD3YySDf

Comment: Are you not using MVVM pattern? My guess from your code is you are trying to auto generate the columns but you columns defined in xaml as well which have no binding, and hence can't display any data.

Comment: I could help you with bindings if I had any idea about the class definition of `Products`. But have a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/01/19/create-wpf-master-detail-ui-using-data-sources-window-object-datasource.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must bind the column to a value in the class of the datagrid items Source

Example:
 If your datagrid.ItemsSource is a table with 3 columns:

```
    - ID
    - Name
    - Address
```

You must bind each column of the datagrid to a column of the table:

```
    ...
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" Width="Auto" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="Auto" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Path=Address}" Width="Auto" />
...
```

Then you'll see the bound values of the table.